# Probability of "at least one event".

Tags: probability

The proportion of the American population that has disease $Z$ is $p=0.02$.  If $55$ people are randomly selected from the population, what is the probability that at least $1$ of them has disease $Z$?

Comment: The event "at least one has the disease" is the complement of the event "none have the disease".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put Austin's comment into an answer, note that the complement of at least one person having the disease is *none* of them having the disease. Do you know how to find the probability that none of them has the disease? Do you know what to do next?

Comment: 1-.02, right? So then the answer would be 1-.98^55? = .6708, I think.

Comment: Exactly the right approach. Dealing with complements is a pretty handy trick.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the help!